# Каким типом потока воспользоваться

Tags: android

Я делаю приложение-видеоплеер с GPS модулем. Одно из этого нужно вынести в отдельный поток. Что и в какой тип потока вынести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользовался AsyngTask засунул туда GPS